# tmux: list all the tmux windows with last 5 lines of output

Tags: tmux

I am running a lot of tmux session like

Each tmux session is started as:

```
today=`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H_%M_%S_%N`
tmux new-session -d -s "$today" zsh /home/path/to/script.sh "with_params"
```

If i want to only view the list of tmux sessions. I can do by

```
 tmux ls | awk '{print $1}';
```

Now what i want is to monitor their output using the while loop to show the session name and the recent output:

```
while true;
do;
        echo "##########################################"  
       ??? For list of tmux session; do
        sleep 1;
        ??? session name
        ??? recent last 5 lines of output
        done
        echo "##########################################"
done;
```

`???` : What commands should i use

Answer (score 2):

You can use `capture-pane` to show the last five lines of output:

```
tmux capture-pane -p -S- -E-|sed '/^$/d'|tail -5
```

Add `-t` to specify the pane you want to see - if you just give a session it will use the active pane in the current window.

Add `-e` if you want colour sequences included.